# Separately execute a section of php code on a web page

Tags: php, magento, curl

This is a best practice type question.  I'm dealing with two different frameworks.  When I execute a piece of code from one framework on the page of another framework, I'm getting a code conflict.  What I'm wondering is how to execute a piece of code on a separate web page and bring in the results AFTER the php on that page has executed and produced its HTML.

#### One Possible Solution

Use Curl - I could house the additional code on a curl page and bring it in that way, but that seems to have a lot of overhead associated with it.

Is there a lower overhead way of doing this than using curl?

#### More info

Specifically in this case I'm trying to use a magento php script in my page, and the autoloader is trying to load in other scripts in the directory that should not be auto loaded.

Comment: You probably better want to fix the problem itself. That's what namespacing is for (or are the frameworks large and hard to port to namespaces?)

Comment: Does the second piece of code need access to the $_SESSION, $_REQUEST vars and the like? If not, you could always invoke it with an exec and skip the web server call...

Comment: @Damp, I can try and see, but I think it needs access to web variable.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve the 'conflict' by wrapping the library code in an class where you define the interface. Then call that class directly.

Adding a server side request to another resource will extend the time each request takes (remember the second request has to fire up a database connection, load the framework, carry out a db query etc).

Comment: I could stick it in a class, but I'm not sure about how defining the interface and how that isolates it from the php that's executing on the page.  Can you shed some light on that.